# How can I prevent java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?

Tags: java, string, int, numberformatexception

While running my code I am getting a `NumberFormatException`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)`
```

How can I prevent this exception from occurring?

Comment: [NumberFormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`"N/A"` is not an integer. It must throw `NumberFormatException` if you try to parse it to an integer.

Check before parsing or handle `Exception` properly.

1. *Exception Handling*

   ```
   try{
       int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
   } catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
       ...
   }
   ```

or - *Integer pattern matching* -

```
String input=...;
String pattern ="-?\\d+";
if(input.matches("-?\\d+")){ // any positive or negetive integer or not!
 ...
}
```

Comment: yes you are right I forgot to assign it to integer value
now i got the error and yes it is resolved successfully 
thank you

Comment: +1 for the integer pattern matching.  I wasn't sure how to do a loop reading a line from stdin using a try/catch.

Comment: @JasonHartley, please review the answer. I have edited it and explained why you would not prefer to use integer pattern matching in your code.

Comment: How to get integer from this type of string "151564" in double quotes

Answer (score 10):

[Integer.parseInt(str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) throws `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable integer. You can hadle the same as below.

```
int a;
String str = "N/A";

try {   
   a = Integer.parseInt(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  // Handle the condition when str is not a number.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Make an exception handler like this,

```
private int ConvertIntoNumeric(String xVal)
{
 try
  { 
     return Integer.parseInt(xVal);
  }
 catch(Exception ex) 
  {
     return 0; 
  }
}

.
.
.
.

int xTest = ConvertIntoNumeric("N/A");  //Will return 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Obviously you can't parse `N/A` to `int` value. you can do something like following to handle that `NumberFormatException` .

```
   String str="N/A";
   try {
        int val=Integer.parseInt(str);
   }catch (NumberFormatException e){
       System.out.println("not a number"); 
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

"N/A" is a string and cannot be converted to a number. Catch the exception and handle it. For example:

```
    String text = "N/A";
    int intVal = 0;
    try {
        intVal = Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //Log it if needed
        intVal = //default fallback value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

'N/A' cannot be parsed to int and we get the exception and there might a case where the provided string could be <-2147483648 or > 2147483648 (int max and min) and in such case too we get number format exception and in such case we can try as below.

```
String str= "8765432198";
Long num= Long.valueOf(str);
int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Integer n=0;
if (num > max) {
        n = max;
    }
if (num < min) {
        n = min;
    }
if (num <= max && num >= min)
  n = Integer.valueOf(str);
```