# String to int conversion with input from Scanner

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string value taken from the keyboard into an int value. I have done it like this before but now I am getting an error which states `NumberFormatException.forInputString`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = "";
int numberChoice;
System.out.println("Please select one of the following options");
choice = input.nextLine();
numberChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice); /*I am getting the error on this line*/
```

The input code is:

```
Data[] temperatures = new Data[7];

for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for day " + (i+1));
        temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a

Comment: You probably typed in something that wasn't a valid number.  If that isn't the issue, there's something else causing a problem in code we can't see.  Did the program give you an exception without giving you a chance to type anything in?  Is there other input taking place before the above code?

Comment: I am typing in valid int variables. Yes there is something taking in input, I have added it to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `Scanner` method that looks at one token, such as `nextDouble()` or `nextInt()`, the scanner will consume the characters in that token, but it will **not** consume the newline character at the end of the line.

This is fine if the next `Scanner` call is to another `nextDouble()`, `nextInt()`, etc., because then that call will skip over the newline.

**However**, if the next call is `nextLine()`, it will return `""`.  `nextLine()` will return everything up to the next newline character; and since it hasn't yet consumed the newline character after the `nextDouble()` call, it will stop at that newline, and return an empty string, without giving you a chance to enter another line.

To solve this, you need to call an extra `nextLine()` to consume the newline:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for day " + (i+1));
        temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
    }
input.nextLine();       // Add this to consume the newline
String choice = "";
int numberChoice;
System.out.println("Please select one of the following options");
choice = input.nextLine();
numberChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that extra ""!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `numberChoice = input.nextInt();` instead of `choice = input.nextLine();` and then convert the string into integer

Comment: Since nextInt uses parseInt to get its result, this will fail in exactly the same cases that the original code does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't accidentally type in a space or a non-numeric character in your input line. I ran your code snippet and it works just fine.

```
Please select one of the following options
6546a  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6546a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at PrimeNumbers.main(PrimeNumbers.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, assuming you enter something that can be parsed as an int. 
Wrap the offending line in a try block and output the error and the contents of choice to see what's going wrong

for example, try this:

```
try {
  numberChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    System.out.println("Failed to parse: ##"+choice+"##"); // mark off the text to see whitespace
}
```

on my machine, this produces

```
/Users/jpk/code/junk:521 $ java SO
Please select one of the following options
two
Failed to parse: ##two##
```