# parseToInt from string in textfile crashing the program

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to generate a hashmap and require some of the strings from a textfile to be integers for the keys. However whenever I try to convert the string to integer the program crashes.

Here is the code below:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("patient.txt"));//create thing to open the file
String line;
while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
{
    String[] text = line.split(",", -1);
    String keyString = text[0];
    String value = text[1] + text[2] + text[3] + text[4];
    int key = Integer.parseInt(keyString);
    System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

The part that causes the program to crash is the parseInt line. I get the error

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Here's a sample of the text file. I am trying to convert Baker into an integer etc.

```
Baker, William,     Chavez,     04/01/05,   04/10/06
Sanchez, Jose,      Chavez,     06/15/05,
```

Comment: Catch `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Comment: closing this, numberformatexception is very much clear, and nobody can do much here unless we have data, that is being passed

Comment: I added a sample of the data from the textfile

Comment: `42` is a number. `Baker` is not. What integer value were you even expecting `Baker` to become?

Comment: I'm trying to make it whatever int it becomes

Comment: Well, as you can see, it doesn't become an integer. Read the javadoc of [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29): *The characters in the string must all be **decimal digits***.

Comment: There is no way to get a *unique* integer from a regular string, so why not just use the string as the key to the hashmap?

Comment: The assignment is to use open addressing to make the hashmap and I don't know how to do it with string keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data does not allow that, if you look carefully into your code, you can see that String keyString = text[0]; is giving your "Baker" for the first line, which is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Handle this exception or
Check if the string its really matching to number format:

```
String input=...;
String pattern ="-?\\d+";
if(input.matches("-?\\d+")){ // any positive or negetive integer or not!
 ...
}
```