# NumberFormatException error from reading a file

Tags: java, filereader, numberformatexception

I've been getting a `NumberFormatException` error when I try to read some data from a text file and convert it to an integer. From what I've seen other people say, this error is caused when an empty string is converted to an integer using `pasreInt()`. But I've been able to print the string '1' from the file into the output. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error even though the string doesn't seem to be empty? Here's my code:

```
try {
        //Retrieve Info
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("BankInfo.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //Skip specified number of lines
        for(int i=0; i<line; i++) {
            br.readLine();
        }

        //Print the string to output
        String holderStr = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(holderStr);

        //The line creating the NumberFormatException
        totalBalNum = (double)Integer.parseInt(holderStr);

        br.close();
        //Read Whole File
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            arrList.add(str);
        }
        br2.close();
    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR! Problem with FileReader. " + e);
    }
```

I know my code is probably really sloppy and inefficient too... I'm a little bit of a noob.

Comment: try `holderStr.trim()` before passing and why are you casting again to Double ? There may be some extra characters also in your string so those can be reason for `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Just to be clear the variable "totalBalNum" is integer or a double?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Comment: Can you provide Stacktrace of the Exception?

Comment: @Deepak  totalBalNum is a double. I've already experimented with that and casting it to a double isn't causing the error. Also trimming the string didn't work.

Comment: @VipulBehl totalBalNum is a double.

Comment: @TechBandit  no that should not cause problem . Alternatively you can use `Double.parseDouble` also. You have to debug for the content what you are trying to convert as Integer . NumberFromatException comes when you try to convert anything to Number and that is not a number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NumberFormatException and how can I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849984/what-is-a-numberformatexception-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think converting string into Integer and then typecasting it to double is causing the error. Why don't you just convert the string to double.
Also you must trim the line while reading it to avoid any spaces.

```
    String holderStr = br.readLine().trim();
    System.out.println(holderStr);

    totalBalNum = Double.parseDouble(holderStr);
```

Comment: Yup! That was the issue. Also I wasn't aware that Double.parseDouble existed until now xD like I said I'm a bit of a noob. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

use `replaceAll()` to convert everything but digits to empty character.

```
holderStr.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

eg.

String `extra34345  dfdf` will be converted to `34345`
String `ab34345ba` will be converted to `34345`
String `\n34345\n` will be converted to `34345`

**The code**

```
String holderStr = br.readLine();

//this line will remove everything from the String, other than Digits
holderStr= holderStr.replaceAll("\\D+","");

System.out.println(holderStr);
```