# MY Program works on bluej but not on hackerrank's online compiler- runtime ERROR NZEC

Tags: java

***Question*** :

Given two weights of `a` and `b` units, in how many different ways you can achieve a weight of `d` units using only the given weights? Any of the given weights can be used any number of times (including 0 number of times).

> Example: 7  can only be achieved by using  2 two times and  3 one
>   time.
>   INPUT 2 3 7    (as a,b,d SEPERATED BY SPACES)
>   OUTPUT:1

My program works fine on bluej but not in hackerearth online compiler. it says Runtime ERROR NZEC my code didn't print anything. Heres my program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class WAYS    
{    
    public static int process(String s)    
    {    
        s=s+" ";    
        int l=s.length();

        String s1="";    
        int n[]=new int[3];    
        int j=0;    

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)    
        {
            char c=s.charAt(i);
            if(c==' ')
            {
                n[j]=Integer.parseInt(s1);
                j++;
                s1="";
            }
            else
            {
                s1=s1+c;
            }
        }
        int a=n[0];
        int b=n[1];
        int d=n[2];
        int q=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=d;i++)
        {
            int f=a*i;              

            for(int k=0;k<=d;k++)
            {
                int f1=b*k;

                if(f+f1==d)
                {
                    q++;
                }
            }
        }
        return q;
    }

    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of Test Cases");
        int T=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String s[]=new String[T];
        int a[]=new int[T];
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("("+(i+1)+")");
            s[i]=br.readLine();
            a[i]=process(s[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can u tell where am i wrong??

Comment: What error do you get while compiling with hackerrank?

Comment: It say something as Runtime Error - NZEC,

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely because you are creating too many in memory variables. You must create variables outside the for loop and manipulate it inside the loop.

EG : `char c=s.charAt(i);` , `int f=a*i;` and `int f1=b*k;`

Comment: It say something as  Runtime Error - NZEC,

Comment: @DipanjanGhosal You are defiantly doing something wrong with your memory I just pointed out a few that i could see up front. Please double check you code. Read https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-various-reasons-that-can-cause-NZEC-error-on-online-coding-platforms

Comment: Also can you post your new code so I can take a look at what you have done.

Comment: i just initialized the variables outside for loop and used them in the loops

Comment: Initializing local variables inside a loop is perfectly ok. That's not what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the statement -

```
n[j]=Integer.parseInt(s1); // since s1 here is ""
```

could be leading to a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) in your code.

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

---

Smallest piece of code to reproduce that is --

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "";
        int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

---

And although I am not sure about the algorithm you are following, would suggest assigning some numeric value as string to `s1` **if** that conversion is a must. Also, do read - 
[How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Comment: @Dipanjan Ghosal wouldn't you want to try something yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem.
WHEN USING JAVA, ALWAYS USE 'String args[]' and' throws Exception' in main method. Example: public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{}
to avoid this silly NZEC error. If that's not working, make return type of your main method to 'int' and return 0 before closing your main method.
Also check for infinite loops.

Comment: Just make your main method `public static void main(String[] args)`. Anything else is *not* a main method! For example, if it doesn't take a String array parameter, then it is not going to be called as a main method, but will be considered just an ordinary method.