# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FALSE"

Tags: java

My Code:

```
public class BehemothSelectGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static DBUtil db = new DBUtil();
private static Populate populate = new Populate();
static int WepHitPoints;
static int ShoulderHitPoints;
static int ChestHitPoints;
static int WristHitPoints;
static int HelmHitPoints;
static int WepAttack;
static int HelmDef;
static int ShoulderDef;
static int WristDef;
static int ChestDef;
static int HelmMoveSpeed;
static int WepMoveSpeed;
static int ChestMoveSpeed;
static int ShoulderMoveSpeed;
static int WristMoveSpeed;

private void cmbMothHeadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String data[][] = db.selectAll("tblBehemoth");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][1].equals((String) cmbMothHead.getSelectedItem())) {
            HelmHitPoints = Integer.parseInt(data[i][2]);
            HelmDef = Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]);
            HelmMoveSpeed = Integer.parseInt(data[i][5]); //StackTrace error
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FALSE"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at leapp.BehemothSelectGUI.cmbMothHeadActionPerformed(BehemothSelectGUI.java:182)
>       at leapp.BehemothSelectGUI.access$100(BehemothSelectGUI.java:12)
>       at leapp.BehemothSelectGUI$2.actionPerformed(BehemothSelectGUI.java:78)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1332)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireContentsChanged(AbstractListModel.java:118)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.setSelectedItem(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:93)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:131)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.addItem(JComboBox.java:716)
>       at leapp.Populate.cmbPop(Populate.java:66)
>       at leapp.BehemothSelectGUI.(BehemothSelectGUI.java:41)
>       at leapp.HeroSelectGUI.btnChooseMothActionPerformed(HeroSelectGUI.java:170)
>       at leapp.HeroSelectGUI.access$000(HeroSelectGUI.java:14)
>       at leapp.HeroSelectGUI$1.actionPerformed(HeroSelectGUI.java:78)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)

I have been using the Integer.parseInt(data[i][number] converter for other variables but only this one throws an error.

UPDATE: 
When I sysoutLine it returns 'FALSE'. I still have no idea how it is returning false as in my database col 5 are number

> System.out.println(data[i][5]);

Comment: And which part of the exception message do you not understand? The value you give to *parse* is "FALSE". That is not a number. So you cant parse it into an int. We can't tell you why you try to parse a string containing a boolean value as number.

Comment: Please check if `data[i][5]` points to the right column in the fetched data

Comment: Check out this answer from the duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18711985/1531124

Comment: And unrelated: learn about java basics first. For example: why to **not** make all fields of your class static. A person who doesn't know why that is a bad idea is most likely **not** ready to create swing UIs or interact with databases. There is that saying: learn to crawl before trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Integer.parseInt(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) java docs very clearly states that.

> Throws: NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable integer.

And **`FALSE`** is not a parsable integer.

All inferreed form your stack trace here:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FALSE" at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: Yes, I get that but I'm not trying to parse FALSE. I'm getting the data from my Database Column which is set to long integers

Comment: @StuartCampbell You might have to share the entire `data[][]` value in that case to validate. The log reads the input string as `FALSE` from somewhere atleast.