# App crash when clearing EditText in Android Studio

Tags: android

I tried to create a Guess Number Game, which I set up a range of number and edit text for user to enter the number. I tried to input, for example "50" but when I tried to delete, I could only delete the "0". If I keep delete the number "5" the app crashed. Here are my MainActivity codes:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView textViewChoice, textViewStatus;
  EditText editTextNum ;

Button buttonSetting;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice);
    textViewStatus =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewStatus);
    editTextNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextGuess);

    buttonSetting =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetting);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("LIMITS",MODE_PRIVATE);




    buttonSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final int MinNumber = preferences.getInt("Seekbar Min", 0);
    final int MaxNumber = preferences.getInt("Seekbar Max", 0);
    textViewChoice.setText("" + MinNumber + "-" + MaxNumber);

    editTextNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int RanNum = random.nextInt(MaxNumber-MinNumber)+MinNumber;
            String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
            int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
            if (EditNum >RanNum){
                textViewStatus.setText("Enter Higher Number");
            }
            else if(EditNum <RanNum){
                textViewStatus.setText("Enter Lower Numer!");


            }
            else if (StringEditNum.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                textViewStatus.setText("You won! You Nutz!");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

After I debugged I get this:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.user.ggame, PID: 3291
>                     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
>                         at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
>                         at com.example.user.ggame.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:71)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9359)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:9446)
>                         at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:11904)
>                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1252)
>                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:573)
>                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:229)
>                         at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:227)
>                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:370)
>                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:71)
>                         at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:479)
>                         at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:148)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:7316)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:7093)
>                         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2688)
>                         at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11662)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1827)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:437)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1818)
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3252)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
>                         at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:351)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4714)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4586)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4331)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4128)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4181)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4307)
>                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4468)
>                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
>                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
>       E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
>                         at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
>                         at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                         at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                         at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: add logcat please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
   Random random = new Random();
   int RanNum = random.nextInt(MaxNumber-MinNumber)+MinNumber;
   String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
    if(!StringEditNum.equals("")){
        int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
        if (EditNum >RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Higher Number");
        }else if(EditNum <RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Lower Numer!");
        }else {
            textViewStatus.setText("You won! You Nutz!");
        }
    } else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Try again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: happy to help , Don't forget to mark as accept answer! check https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here in this line:

```
 String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
 int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
```

While clearing the `5` the value of `StringEditNum` will be empty string and you cannot parseInt empty string so it is crashing

try adding this :

```
String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
int EditNum = 0;
if(!StringEditNum.equals("")){
   EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below.

```
editTextNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

      if(editTextNum.getText().toString().length() > 0)
      {
        Random random = new Random();
        int RanNum = random.nextInt(MaxNumber-MinNumber)+MinNumber;
        String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
        int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
        if (EditNum >RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Higher Number");
        }
        else if(EditNum <RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Lower Numer!");
        }
        else if (StringEditNum.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            textViewStatus.setText("You won! You Nutz!");
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. This will produce  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0` because bound should be `random.nextInt(bound)` 0<=bound

   ```
      Random random = new Random();
      int RanNum = random.nextInt(MaxNumber-MinNumber)+MinNumber;

      try this

       Random random = new Random();
       int RanNum = random.nextInt((MaxNumber-MinNumber)+1);
   ```

2.String should not be null when converting to integer

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        Random random = new Random();
        int RanNum = random.nextInt((MaxNumber-MinNumber)+1);
        String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextNum.getText().toString()))
            {
                int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
                if (EditNum >RanNum){
                    textViewStatus.setText("Enter Higher Number");
                }
                else if(EditNum <RanNum){
                    textViewStatus.setText("Enter Lower Numer!");


                }
                else if (StringEditNum.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    textViewStatus.setText("You won! You Nutz!");
                }
            }else {

            }            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check **StringEditNum** not null or empty before convert it in to **int**

```
    if(!StringEditNum.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

            int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using a textWatcher listener and whenever you write/delete something this listener is called. Now when you write the number 50 you write 5 and 0. Then when you delete it you first delete 0 which leaves 5. In this situation the following line is good

```
int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
```

but when you delete the 5 the StringEditNum becomes "" and the above line will cause a java.lang.NumberFormatException. so please check the code below to make it work perfectly

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textViewChoice, textViewStatus;
EditText editTextNum ;

Button buttonSetting;
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

textViewChoice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice);
textViewStatus =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewStatus);
editTextNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextGuess);

buttonSetting =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetting);
preferences = getSharedPreferences("LIMITS",MODE_PRIVATE);




  buttonSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,        SecondaryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
final int MinNumber = preferences.getInt("Seekbar Min", 0);
final int MaxNumber = preferences.getInt("Seekbar Max", 0);
textViewChoice.setText("" + MinNumber + "-" + MaxNumber);

editTextNum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int RanNum = random.nextInt(MaxNumber-MinNumber)+MinNumber;
        String StringEditNum= editTextNum.getText().toString();
        if(!StringEditNum.equals("")){
        int EditNum = Integer.parseInt(StringEditNum);
        if (EditNum >RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Higher Number");
        }
        else if(EditNum <RanNum){
            textViewStatus.setText("Enter Lower Numer!");


        }

        else {
            textViewStatus.setText("You won! You Nutz!");
        }
    }else{
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```