# Can't pass converted integer to a database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, parseint

I have this script that is supposed to add an integer to an SQLite database.

```
//SIMPLIFIED SCRIPT FOR DEMONSTRATING PURPOSES
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    AddBuilding(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());   //Convert input String to int and add it to the database.
}

public void AddBuilding(int code) {
String sql = "INSERT INTO Buildings (Code) VALUES (?)"; 

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, code);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

When I try to convert a text field string to an integer and pass it to the database I get the following error. When I try to pass an actual integer, it works without a problem.
e.g. ( AddBuilding(1); )

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jTextField1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at diaxirisikoinoxriston.Add_Building.jButton1ActionPerformed(Add_Building.java:169)
at diaxirisikoinoxriston.Add_Building.access$100(Add_Building.java:7)
at diaxirisikoinoxriston.Add_Building$2.actionPerformed(Add_Building.java:76)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Textfield.getText() method giving **"jTextField1"** as String . Please validate the input of your text field to be integer only or figure out why getText() method giving textfield name in return.

Comment: So, it seems it returns the initial contents of the text field from the start of the program. How is this even possible? Shouldn't it return the current input when I call it?

Comment: Yes, it should return the input in your textfield. Try this to check value:
String value=jTextField1.getText();
System.out.println(value);

Comment: It prints the initial value that the textfield contains on the start of the program.
It seems it doesn't get updated when I write something else

Comment: Have you hardcoded that value?, If yes, please try without any intial value.

Comment: The same, it only accepts the initial value. If there's not an initial value it doesn't work as well.

Comment: are you implementing ActionListner Interface?