# Read and Write to a file

Tags: java

I am having to make a gui project for my CSIS class and I am having trouble with the read and Write I am using. I am making a game where you battle stuff and after you beat five of them it shows a message saying "YOU WIN". Every time you win a battle, I have it write the number of wins to a file so if you were to close the game you can continue when it is opened again. Here is the code that i have Written - this is my read method.

```
    private static int read() 
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    try(Scanner reader = new Scanner("wins.txt"))
    {
        while(reader.hasNextLine())
        {
            String read = reader.nextLine();
            returnValue = Integer.parseInt(read);
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("No such File! Please Try Again! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return returnValue;
```

and this is my Write method.

```
    private static void write(int wins) 
{
    try(Formatter writer = new Formatter("wins.txt");)
    {
        writer.format("%d", wins);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("File not Found!!");
    }

}
```

the only thing that is in the wins.txt file is the number that the Write method writes into it. so i win once then the file will have "1" and if i win twice then it will have "2"

Whenever I run the program, it throws a NumberFormatException. I am not sure why it is doing this because I am parseing the String that that reader reads into an int.

Comment: If this isn't going to work, is there any other way i would be able to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-to-resolve-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Comment: Please add your `wins.txt` contents

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. You should include the relevant part of the input file as well.

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have added what is in the wins.txt file.

Comment: @EJP how would i make it so i would read what i did write?

Comment: I don't see why you are using a Formatter here. Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this code...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner("wins.txt")
```

... constructs a `Scanner` [with the literal text "wins.txt"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-), not the contents of the file "wins.txt".

To read a file with a `Scanner`, the easiest way for you is probably to [construct it using a `File` object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-)...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("wins.txt"))
```

There are some other changes you will need to make to your code to get it to work from this point, but this should cover the major issue.