# Alternative way to getting numeric value from edittext

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using the following line of code to get the value from an edittext:

```
          double value = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString().trim());
```

This is inside an onclick method. The app I'm developing crashes every time that button is clicked, and I've commented every possible variation of lines in the method and figured out that it's this line of code that causes it to crash. I have no idea why this is happening, but is there an alternative to the same? Parsing it as double didn't work either.

Comment: This code works fine on its own. Please show the stacktrace to the crash

Comment: You might be getting `NumberFormatException` because you're trying to convert empty string to Double value.

Comment: or an invalid number

Comment: you need first check your edit text value that it should not be empty or blank spaces or invalid number

Comment: Refer this [How can I prevent java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “N/A”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18711896/7666442)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that crash is bc you are usng trim on null or empty value.
try adding check

```
 double value=0.0;
    if(null!=editText && null!=editText.getText() && editText.getText().length() > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())){
     value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString().trim());
    }else{
    editText.setError("Your message");
    }
```

Comment: What if the EditText itself is null?

Comment: You might also want to try `TextUtils.isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble(String)` returns a **primitive** **double** type.

`Double.valueOf(String)` returns a **wrapper** object of type **Double**

So you can do it following way,

```
String strValue = editText.getText().toString().trim();
```

Check Value is empty or not.

```
if(!strValue.isEmpty()) {
      double value = Double.parseDouble(strValue);
}
```

**OR**

```
if(!strValue.isEmpty()) {
      Double value = Double.valueOf(strValue);
}
```

Comment: This still throws an exception on empty strings

Comment: Yah. Developer has to check if it is not empty.

Comment: An EditText cannot have a null string, though

Comment: Sorry I mean to say Empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  String s=editText.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("")&& !s.equalsIgnoreCase(null)&& !s.isEmpty()) {
        Double value = Double.parseDouble(s);

    }else{
//alert
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recommend**

Use the `isEmpty` method of `TextUtils` class.

```
double value;
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString().trim())){
    value = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

> Implementation of isEmpty Method of TextUtils :

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```