# I want convert String to long

Tags: java, spring, string

I have String like this `""3333""`  I want convert to `Long`
but when convert I am seeing this Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

I try many ways but I cant convert

I am trying this way

```
public void addNewFriend(List<String> mobileList, String login) {
    try {
        List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
        mobileList.forEach(x -> {
            log.debug(x);
            x=x.replace("\\\"","");
            Long y = Long.parseLong(x);
            log.debug(y.toString());
            list.add(y);
        });
        log.debug(list.toString());
        Set<AppUser> appUsers = appUserRepository.findByMobileNumberIn(list);
        if (appUsers.size() > 0) {
            AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findByLogin(login);
            appUser.friends(appUsers);
            appUserRepository.save(appUser);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("cannot find user relation with author", "AppUser", "List is Empty");
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("Cannot find User", "Url", "Check your input");

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("cannot find user relation with author", "AppUser", "List is Empty");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException(e.getMessage(), "Server Error", "Check it!");
    }


}
```

**note: I am take this request from kafka I can't get mobile list in long direct**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711896/how-can-i-prevent-java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string-n-a)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `\\` because `\\\"` will look for `\"` which is not the case with your string.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Long.parseLong("\"3333\"".replace("\"", "")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3333
```

Comment: ""333"" not static but my solution  below this answer

Answer (score -1):

Just soultion change replace to replaceAll
like this

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
mobileList.forEach(x -> {
    log.debug(x);
    x=x.replaceAll("\\\"","");
    Long y = Long.parseLong(x);
    log.debug(y.toString());
    list.add(y);
});
```

Comment: `replace("\"", "")` and `replaceAll("\\\"","")` will both produce the same result, but the second uses regex, and there is no need for that. Since the first is simpler, you should accept the [answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952451/5221149).

Comment: i cant accept  anthor soultion because my input  like this ` ["[""33333"",""44444"", ""11111"
",""2020""]" ` @Andreas

Comment: Did you test both the replace("\"", "") and replaceAll("\\\"", "") solutions?

Comment: `replace("\"", "")` and `replaceAll("\\\"","")` does the **exact same thing**, i.e. fix the problem with the `replace("\\\"","")` in the question, so I can't see why you can't accept Arvind's answer, which tells you to use the simpler `replace("\"", "")`, with proof that it works.